# SAS IOM Data Provider - Access Denied - SSIS connection

Tags: sql, ssis, sas, integration

I'm looking for guidance into how to integrate with the SAS IOM Data Provider through SSIS. It works fine when using SAS software but when trying to connect using the SAS IOM Data Provider in SSIS I receive the error message "Access is denied". The server name and credentials are identical.

Comment: Welcome to SO! There should be a minimum content in one question: Input sample (if needed), expected output sample (is needed), what you try, what you research... Could you show us some more information as your setup, error...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try and get the specific error message you receive and what O/S you are running on (SAS O/S and SSIS O/S). It is most likely using the wrong credentials. Check SSIS logs and the Event Viewer. You need to determine which system is rejecting the call. Most likely it is SAS which means you are coming across, to SAS, as a different user than you think you are.

Also, provide your connection string to IOM or double-check it at https://www.connectionstrings.com/sas-iom-provider/.

Comment: Thanks AlanC for the comments, I followed your advice and found that I had to connect to the metadata server which was hidden under the advanced tab as well as the data source. And then I used the right credentials and it worked.